# Android 7.1.1 showing insuficient space even with plenty of space in SD card formatted as internal

Tags: sd-card, 7.1-nougat, formatting

I have a ZTE Maven 3, it comes with 8GB of internal memory so i bought a 16GB microSD and formatted it as internal storage with the built-in android option to do so.

Problem is, when i try to install new apps the PlayStore refuses because i dont have enough space, but even if the internal storage is at full capacity, the SD card is 90% empty !

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep your internal storage empty because all the apps which you download from play store gets into your internal storage not in your external storage, even if you buy a sd card of 128GB or 256 GB you will not be able to install apps if you have full internal storage

Suggestion: Move all your photos ,videos, downloads to your SD Card
manually and  especially delete that .Thumbnails folder(Hidden Folder)
in DCIM in internal storage.

Comment: Once I've done that, my apps are still taking up too much space. I'ved tried moving all the apps I can. Is there anyway to view/debug what's hogging the space?